# Reasons for using React.cloneElement?

Tags: reactjs

May be it's philosophical question, but what is a reasons for using React.cloneElement? Anybody have simple example, or 'usecase' for it?

Comment: I also find documentation to be much more helpful when "why" is explained.

Answer (score 0):

You have indeed an [example of use-case with react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/passing-props-to-children/app.js).

React.cloneElement can be useful when, with nested components, you want the parent component to pass additional props to children components.